# out of memory in recycler adapter

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I have stored images as type -image- in My database(Sqlserver) the problem is when I try to send it to android as type byte[] I had out of memory error because I try try to load all images in the same time  ... 
one of the solution that I found it  here is to send images as link and get only imags need it 
 now I want to get only the link of image in php and send it to android
I dont know how to convert image(Stored in DB) to link in php and send it to android

```
    public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.MyTag>{
LayoutInflater inflater;
DbConnection db ;
CnxExternal myConex = new CnxExternal();
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listitem;
private CardAdapter.MyTag holder;
Context ctx;
ArrayList<byte[]> img , imgfou ;
ArrayList<String>nomesFo,descriptions;
String codeBar;
ArrayList<Integer>idfourns;



public CardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list,ArrayList<byte[]>imagbyt,ArrayList<String>names,ArrayList<Integer>idf,String cod,ArrayList<String>Description,ArrayList<byte[]>imagfour) {
    super();
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.listitem = list;
    ctx=context;
    this.img=imagbyt;
    this.nomesFo=names;
    this.idfourns=idf;
    this.codeBar=cod;
    this.imgfou=imagfour;
    this.descriptions=Description;
    db =new DbConnection(ctx);

}

public class MyTag extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView price;
    TextView name;
    ImageView img;
    TextView namfou;
    TextView rating;
    FloatingActionButton btnlike;

    CardView cardView;
    public MyTag(View view) {
        super(view);
        //for animat
cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prixprodtestcard);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomprodtestcard);
        namfou=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtestockcard);
        rating=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageprodcard);
        btnlike = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.likeButtoncard);
}
}


@Override
public MyTag onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);

    return new MyTag(v);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listitem.size();
}


@Override
public void onViewRecycled(MyTag holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Glide.clear(holder.img);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyTag holder, final int position) {

    //anim fadein
    YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInUp)
            .playOn(holder.cardView);

    final HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>)listitem.get(position);


    if(map.get("like").equals("0")){
        holder.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }else{
        holder.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);

    }
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx,InformationsProduit.class);
            i.putExtra("nomProd",map.get("name"));
            i.putExtra("prix",map.get("price"));
            i.putExtra("nomFour",nomesFo.get(position));
            i.putExtra("image",img.get(position));
            i.putExtra("telFour",map.get("telefournisseur"));
            i.putExtra("addrFour",map.get("adressFou"));
            i.putExtra("idFour",idfourns.get(position));
           i.putExtra("description",descriptions.get(position));
            i.putExtra("codeBar",codeBar);
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    holder.price.setText(map.get("price"));
    holder.name.setText(map.get("name"));
    holder.namfou.setText(nomesFo.get(position));
    holder.rating.setText(map.get("rating"));


    Glide.with(ctx)
            .load(imgfou.get(position))
            //.diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
            //.skipMemoryCache( true )
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .into(holder.img);


    holder.btnlike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        CardAdapter.MyTag hld=holder;
        int pos=position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            HashMap<String, String> mapclicked = (HashMap<String, String>)listitem.get(pos);
            if(mapclicked.get("like").equals("0"))
            {
                hld.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                mapclicked.put("like", "1");


                Snackbar snackbar;
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(hld.btnlike, "Bien ajouter au prefere", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                snackbar.show();

                db.insertFav(codeBar,idfourns.get(pos) , map.get("name") , map.get("price") , nomesFo.get(position) , map.get("adressFou") , map.get("telefournisseur") ,img.get(position) );

                hld.btnlike.startAnimation(animAdp());

            }else{
                hld.btnlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                mapclicked.put("like", "0");

        Snackbar.make(hld.btnlike, "Removed from prefere" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

                db.deleteR(codeBar,idfourns.get(pos));
                hld.btnlike.startAnimation(animAdp());
            }
        }}
    );



}
```

Comment: try this solution it's helpful : [load-image-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876455/load-image-from-php-directly-into-glide/42877004#42877004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had out of memory because you try to get all images in the same file Json

try this solution :

```
 Glide.with(ctx)
             .load("http://192.168.1.8/connect/getimage.php")
              .into(holder.img);
```

the Script PHP ==>getimage.php

```
$sql="select img from table where id=1032 ";


    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $this->connection, $sql);
    $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

    $information = array();
    while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
        {
            $img=$data['img'];
        }

        echo $img;
```