# load image from php directly into Glide

Tags: php, android, android-glide

I have images as `byte []` and I will load it directly into `Glide` 
some thing like this :

the Glide in recyclerView (Adapter):

```
Glide.with(ctx)
    .load("http://192.168.1.8/connect/getimage.php")
    .into(holder.img);
```

The script PHP ==> `getimage.php`

```
$sql = "select img from table where id=1032 ";


$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this - > connection, $sql);
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

$information = array();
while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $img = base64_encode($data['img']);
}

echo $img;
```

I would get It directly without Json 
to put it into Glide  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this ligne

```
$img=base64_encode($data['img']);
```

by :

```
$img=$data['img'];
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send image as base64 string. Just send it as ordinary file.

Comment: Could you give me example
I don't Understand what should I do